# NotificationListenerService is not getting bound to SystemUI on Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Based on my testing, it appears that the `NotificationListenerService`(NLS) in my android app is not getting bound to the system on Android 8 (Oreo). I am targeting my app for SDK version 26 to make it compatible with the new OS.

Prior to Android N, the NLS service was bound to SystemUI forever [(Ref: Google I/O 2016)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eFQbC5r17w&feature=youtu.be&t=2221). Starting from Android N, two new methods were introduced in NLS service: `requestRebind(ComponentName)` and `requestUnbind()`.

In Android Oreo, there are new [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) that apply to services. However, it does not apply for certain services, such as a "Notification listener that another app binds to". This is my use case, as I am using an NLS service that is supposed to be bound to the SystemUI.

However, as I observed, this service is never getting bound to SystemUI. Additionally, even if I explicitly call `requestRebind(ComponentName)`, the service is never getting bound and hence it is non-functional because this means I am unable to listen to notifications.

How do I fix this problem in Android Oreo?

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, this is silly! The issue was resolved by a reboot. I suppose Android was misbehaving on my phone and simply refused to work the right way. Rebooting the phone and trying again made the service work the way it is supposed to!

I'll leave this question up as a reminder to all that sometimes the simplest and most cliched fix (i.e. *"Did you try turning it off and on again?"*) is the right answer!

Good grief!